# Generalised linear mixed effect model(gamer)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, neuroscience

I have total of 230 subjects where each subject has 82 volume data of 82 brain region. Not all but many subjects have gone time point 1, time point 2 and time point 3 scans. So, this leads to total of 506 observations in total. Now, I want to use glmer function in R to calculate the rate of change of the volume in all-time point in each subject of each brain region individually and group analysis.

my dataset include row= subject|group(healthy control &Patient)|timepoints|all 82 brain regions

I would like to know how should I perform glmer function. how can I calculate the difference in volume in each subject in T1, T2 and T3 in a loop?

help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As stated it looks more like a software-related issue, which is [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Perhaps you could reframe it as a statistical question by emphasizing the experimental design and how to turn the contrasts of interest into statistical tests following `glmer` estimation.

Comment: Could you answer me how should I perform difference in volume change in each subject's T1 and T2 using loop or similar function.